# Compilation error when trying to modularize some standard headers c++

Tags: c++, g++, c++20, c++-modules

I'm trying to compile some header files into a module one so I could test it whether it works or not using this compiler option:

```cpp
g++ -fmodules-ts -std=c++20 -c -x c++-system-header <file-name>
```

where `<file-name>` is the name of the header such as `string_view`.

However, not all headers work harmoniously, this the list of the headers that won't compile with common errors such as inconsistent import macro definition of `NULL`, `__stdcall`, recursive lazy load pointing to class `allocator`, and I/O functions not found at scope such as `vsnprintf`. Some errors commonly pointed to `<pthread.h>` and `<process.h>` c-headers.

- `<bitset>`
- `<memory_resource>`
- `<stdexcept>`
- `<system_error>`
- `<string>`
- `<iterator>`
- `<ranges>`
- `<algorithm>`
- `<execution>`
- `<complex>`
- `<random>`
- `<locale>`
- `<ios>`
- `<istream>`
- `<ostream>`
- `<iostream>`
- `<fstream>`
- `<sstream>`
- `<syncstream>`
- `<iomanip>`
- `<streambuf>`
- `<filesystem>`
- `<regex>`
- `<thread>`
- `<stop_token>`
- `<mutex>`
- `<shared_mutex>`
- `<future>`
- `<condition_variable>`
- `<span>`

Headers that are not mentioned above are compiled successfully.

**NOTE**: I'm using GCC version 11.1.

---

### Update

Some headers are resolved by myself and the only headers that can't be compiled are:

- `<execution>`
- `<locale>`
- `<iomanip>`
- `<filesystem>`
- `<thread>`
- `<stop_token>`
- `<condition_variable>`

As I've mentioned above from the first one, the only common error they are sharing is the *inconsistency import macro definition of `NULL`*

Comment: Modules have been added to the language with C++20, but the modularization of the standard library comes with the C++23 standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, yes. my goal is to compile all standard library headers.

Comment: You can't create modules out of standard library header just by compiling them, that's not how modules work. What you're doing is essentially creating *pre-compiled* headers, which is a different thing.

Comment: ok, so it means, when I include `import <iostream>`, it maps to the pre-compiled header? why it has the same `.gcm` file extension as the other custom module?

Comment: See this meta-bug: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99227. If you have additional feedback, please report there.